# How do I run a Java application on Html for Github pages

Tags: java, html, github

I have a Java game that's played through the terminal and I wanted to add it to my Portfolio website on Github pages. I was able to have Github use an html file in my repository to start with but other than that, nothing. The game doesn't have any graphics its just text.

This is the main file, It calls a few other files but basically it runs random events until the player "wins" or dies. I think if this part is able to run I can probably get the others to run as they're all just hardcoded containers called at random.
`
import java.util.Scanner;

public class JourneyHome {

```
public static void charText(String sen, long time)
{
    long pause = time*3;
    for (int i = 0; i <sen.length(); i++)
    {
        System.out.print(sen.charAt(i));
        if(sen.charAt(i) == '.' || sen.charAt(i) == ',' || sen.charAt(i) == '?' || sen.charAt(i) == '!')
        {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(pause);
            } catch (InterruptedException e){
                //Should not happen
            }
        }

        else{
            try {
                Thread.sleep(time);
            } catch (InterruptedException e){
                //Should not happen
            }
        }
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException  {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
     Player user= Player.getInstance();
     Monsters monster;
     String userName, input;
     Event event;
     
    Scanner userInput = new Scanner(System.in);
    
    charText("You wake up to find yourself in an unfamiliar place. Where are you? WHO are you? \nWhat is your name?", 100);
    System.out.println("");
    userName = userInput.nextLine();
    
    user.setPlayerName(userName);
    System.out.println("");

    charText(user.getPlayerName()+". Your name is "+ user.getPlayerName()+". Remembering, you sigh a breath of relief, "
    + "but you still don't\nknow where you are. Find your way home.", 100);
    System.out.print(" [Press Enter to Continue]");
    System.out.println("");
    
     do {
        input = userInput.nextLine();
        if (input.isEmpty()) 
        {
            event = new Event();    
            if (event.isAmbushed())
            {
                monster = event.getMonster();
                event.setAmbushed(false);
                new Combat(monster);
            }
            
        }


        else 
        {
            if (input.charAt(0) == 'S' || input.charAt(0) == 's')
            {
                    user.displayAllStats();
                    System.out.println("");
                    Thread.sleep(500);
            }
        }
         
     }while (true);
    

}
```

}

`

I saw things like Applet but it looks like that's been deprecated and I can't use it. I've also tried Teavm but I didn't find any updated versions of flavour and the one that on the website isn't showing the java and having trouble loading the tester. I want to try and keep it as a java application so I don't want to use JSweet (yet).

Comment: I'd just capture a short run of the application using a simple screen grabber capable of writing it out to an animated gif [for example](https://github.com/RustyKnight/CircularTickerTap)